# Excel to Flat File with text qualifier " in SSMS

Tags: sql, excel, ssms, export-to-csv

Hi I'm new to SSMS and would really appreciate some help. I have an excel file with 80,000 rows. I am trying to to use the import and export wizard in SSMS to convert it into a csv file with a double quote identifier (flat file). It seemed to be working but it is only exporting about 10,000 rows.

It says:

[image]

[image]

What can I do to export the whole file? Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to use the SSMS export wizard for this? It's simpler to use Excel, "File, Save as CSV" to directly convert your Excel sheet to CSV.

Comment: Hi Edward! I need the '' as identifier and so I've been trying to use SSMS

Comment: Do you have a column named "ErrorCode" on your Excel Sheet1? If so, rename it to something else, like "ErrorCod". "ErrorCode" is used for error redirection in SSIS. This should make the error message go away.